# Iterating over numbers within XPath

Tags: python, html, xml, selenium, xpath

I am using the Selenium webdriver in Python to find elements on a web page to process, in the way shown below:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="gsc-cursor-page" and text()="1"]')
```

Ideally, I would like to go through all the texts within that div, `text()="1"`,  `text()="2"`, ... `text()="10"`, etc. But since the whole xpath is a string, somehow I cannot find a way to write an iteration `for i in range(10)` without breaking the inner structure.

The closest I could get is

```
mypath = '//div[@class="gsc-cursor-page" and text()="' + str(i) + '"]'
next =  driver.find_element_by_xpath(path)
```

But this also leads to error. Any suggestions on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Looping is correct.Try to put some wait. Or else can you share the website?

Comment: @carl_pch *"But this also leads to error"*. And the error message is....?

Comment: @KishanPatel and har07: thanks for the response! please see my updated question with additional information!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//div[@class="gsc-cursor-page" and number() >= 1 and number() <= 10]
```

will select all of the `div` elements of the specified `@class` with values in the range of `1..10`.

---

**Specific Python/Selenium code to address OP's comment**

```
xp = "//div[@class="gsc-cursor-page" and number() >= 1 and number() <= 10]"

for div in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xp):
    div.click()
```

Comment: Thanks! sorry for not clarifying this earlier but I am not simply try to select all i at once, but want to click on each i iteratively (see my updated question)

Comment: Simply iterate over the selected `div` list in Python and click each in Selenium as you normally would.

Answer (score -1):

somehow I am able to put in the variable for iteration through "position" instead of usnig the internal text of a div. thanks for all of your helps and tips!

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="gsc-cursor"]/div[position()='+str(i)+']')
```

Comment: This is completely different than what you asked.  You asked about, and your example showed, tests against the ***numeric content*** of `div` elements.  This answer iterates over `div` elements not based on their ***numeric content*** but rather based on their ***position***.